# How to get SVG circle to drag along SVG path?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created a JSFiddle where I want to be able to drag a circle along a path, but I am having problems. Here is the link to the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fHBpC/2/

Here are the problems I am having:

1. Inside of dragMove, the argument "d" is undefined.
2. My path is supposed to start at (0,0) go to (200, 200) and end at (150, 150), but instead it only starts at (0, 0) and goes to (200, 200).
3. How do I get the circle to only drag along the line?

Corresponding code:

1.

```
function dragMove(d) {
    console.log("dragging a circle");
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('x', d.x)
        .attr('y', d.y)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
}
```

2.

```
var path = content.append("path").attr("d", "M 100 100 L 200 200 L 150 150").style("stroke-width", 5).style("stroke", "steelblue");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `this` to reference the circle element. But there are some more problems with the `dragMove()` function.

   - Note that the circle does not have properties `x` and `y`, they're called `cx` and `cy`.
   - Those properties aren't numbers, they are of type `SVGAnimatedLength`. This means, you can not do arithmetics with them.
   - You're trying to move the circle in three manners:

     1. By changing the properties
     2. By setting the attributes for the circle's center
     3. By means of a `transform`
   - One of those methods would be sufficient. Also, `transform` is independent of the `cx`/`cy` properties/attributes, i.e. it moves the circle an additional amount so that the circle would travel twice as far as you intended.
2. When going back the last bit from 200,200 to 150,150, your path does not add an additional "coat of paint" that would be distinguishable from the paint that's already been applied when going from 0,0 to 200,200.
3. That's really difficult and depends on your intended behavior when the pointer leaves the path. The most intuitive behavior would probably be that the circle would always move to the point on the path that's closest to the pointer. However, this is a non-trivial calculation that needn't even have an unambiguous result, unless it's a simple straight line, where it's pretty easy. The only help you have is the [`getPointAtLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGPathElement#Methods) method that returns a point. This means, you could use a down or right movement of the pointer to move the circle further to the end of the path, and analogously use left or up movement to move it further to the start (see [fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMeYV/)). This has some drawbacks, namely in general, even if the pointer is on the path, the circle will be somewhere else (in your example that won't be the case because the initial path segment is a 45° stroke), and how can I reach the path's end if I've reached the screen's edge and can't move further? Alternatively, you could throw a few values at `getPointAtLength()` and pick the one that's closest to the pointer position.